# ReactNative - Sending images in socket.io

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, socket.io, expo

I've got a problem and I was wondering if someone here could help me. It occurs when I upload pictures from the app to the server.
I use React-native and socket.io to transfer my data.

I transfer the pictures via websocket in Base64. I don't have problem when the weight of the image is low. But when it is high, the transfer doesn't work.

I don't know who to fix this.

How can I avoid this please? And do you know what may cause this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem, I used [ImageManipulator](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagemanipulator/#imagemanipulatormanipulateasyncuri-actions-saveoptions) with this configuration :

```js
const manipulator = await ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync(uri, [
        {resize: {width: 500, height: 500}}
    ], {
        compress: 1,
        format: ImageManipulator.SaveFormat.PNG,
        base64: true
    })
```